# Style BottomNavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying out Flutter and I am trying to change the colour of the `BottomNavigationBar` on the app but all I could achieve was change the colour of the `BottomNavigationItem` (icon and text).

Here is where  i declare my `BottomNavigationBar`:

```
class _BottomNavigationState extends State<BottomNavigationHolder>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      body: pages(),
      bottomNavigationBar:new BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
              title: new Text("Home")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.work),
              title: new Text("Self Help")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.face),
              title: new Text("Profile")
          )
        ],
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int i){setState((){index = i;});},
        fixedColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Earlier I thought I had it figured out by editing `canvasColor` to green on my main app theme but it messed up the entire app colour scheme:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        canvasColor: Colors.green
      ),
      home: new FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I also wanted to change much of the bottomnav, I ended up just copying all the code of the bottomnav and change what I wanted. I guess that is one of the main benefits of Flutter, the openness and ease to do that. I made this: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPkoxKWX0AEg9tF.jpg:large

Answer (score 164, accepted):

There is no option to specify the background color of `BottomNavigationBar` but to change the `canvasColor`. One way you can achieve it without messing up the whole app would be by wrapping `BottomNavigationBar` in a `Theme` with desired `canvasColor`.

Example:

```
  bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
        canvasColor: Colors.green,
        // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
        textTheme: Theme
            .of(context)
            .textTheme
            .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow))), // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
    child: new BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: 0,
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
          title: new Text("Add"),
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
          title: new Text("Delete"),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much good Sir. Worked perfectly. Do you know anyway of changing the colours of the inactive icons on the bottom navigation bar?

Comment: `ThemeData` has a `disabledColor` property, try setting it.

Comment: I have actually tried setting all the available attributes under `ThemeData` to change the inactive icon colour and none of them had an effect hey. Even `disabledColor`

Comment: Actually the disabled color is fetched from `caption` of `textTheme`. I've updated my answer to show how can you achive it. Hope that helps!

Comment: man you the best! Thank you so much.. I doubt I would've figured that out by myself honestly! Thank you so so much!!

Comment: @HemanthRaj when i am using this theme for changing the bottomnavigation color then shadow of the bottomnavigation bar is not showing.Can you please tell me how to show the shadow of the bottomnavigaton bar?

Comment: @WitVault You can stack a container with gradient behind the bottom nav bar and make bottom nav bar have a transparent color. I've not tried it myself, hope you can give it a try.

Comment: Why does this not work with Type shifting? How would you theme that?

Comment: Changing the type to fixed solves all the issues. No need to wrap inside a theme widget or anything like that. Theming related properties are alreasy available in the Bottom navigation widget so you won't need Theme widget

Answer (score 149):

`BottomNavigationBar` could be either fixed or moving (shifting).
It is fixed if there are 3 items and changes to shifting for 4 or more items. We can override this behavior by setting `BottomNavigationBar.type` parameter.

- #### Fixed `BottomNavigationBar`

  [image]

  ```dart
  BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, // Fixed 
    backgroundColor: Colors.black, // <-- This works for fixed
    selectedItemColor: Colors.greenAccent,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.call),
        label: 'Call',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.message),
        label: 'Message',
      ),
    ],
  )
  ```

---

- #### Shifting `BottomNavigationBar`:

  [image]

  ```dart
  BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting, // Shifting
    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.call),
        label: 'Call',
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue, // <-- This works for shifting
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.message),
        label: 'Message',
        backgroundColor: Colors.green, // <-- This works for shifting
      ),
    ],
  )
  ```

Comment: That's works, Thanks. And BTW dont forget to remove the icon color in BottomNavigationBarItem.

Answer (score 86):

The accepted answer isn't entirely wrong. However, `BottomNavigationBar` does in-fact have a property of `backgroundColor`. As per the documentation

> If type is BottomNavigationBarType.shifting and the itemss, have BottomNavigationBarItem.backgroundColor set, the item's backgroundColor will splash and overwrite this color.

What this means is that the `BottomNavigation`'s backgroundColor will be overriden by the individual items backgroundColor because the default type is `BottomNavigationBarType.shifting`.

To fix this, simply add the following property to the declared `BottomNavigationbar` widget.

```
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```

**Note**: If you do, however, want the shifting effect you will have to declare colors for each item, or wrap the widget that allows the overriding of the child widget(s) background color.

i.e Something like `Container` widget.

Comment: i changed `type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting`  by `type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed`. this worked for me, thanks

Comment: i had an issue with backgroundColor being changed to white automatically as soon as i add 4 children.  After setting the navBar type to fixed, it stopped changing automatically.

Answer (score 19):

can change by setting colors to  backgroundColor property if type is fixed.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon:Icon(Icons.home, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                title: new Text('Home'),),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.work,color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                title: new Text('Self Help'),),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon:Icon(Icons.face, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                title: new Text('Profile'),),
          ]
        )
```

If the type is shifting it will use color inside bottomNavigationBarItem.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon:Icon(Icons.home, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                title: new Text('Home'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.red),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.work,color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                title: new Text('Self Help'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon:Icon(Icons.face, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                title: new Text('Profile'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.amber),
          ]

        )
```

You can see even though I have set backgroundColor property it does not apply that colors and the background color inside BottomNavigationBarItem widget will override that.

Found from [here](https://mightytechno.com/flutter-bottom-navigation/)

Comment: `title` is now deprecated, it says to use `label` instead which takes a String

Answer (score 12):

Set following properties to change the **background**, **selected** and **unselected** colors

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        ...
)
```

Comment: type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, this property is very important

Answer (score 12):

You can currently style them `BottomNavigationBar` directly from the `Theme`, like this:

```
ThemeData(
    bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        elevation: 10,
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFFA67926), fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 14.0
        ),
        unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey[600], fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 12.0
        ),
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFA67926),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[600],
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
    ),
)
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it with themes. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It took me ages of searching to find this. Thanks for putting me out of my misery xD

Answer (score 6):

The `title` is deprecated. We use `label` instead. 
For `label`, we can use corresponding attributes: `selectedLabelStyle, unselectedLabelStyle`. 
For example:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          selectedFontSize: 0,
          unselectedFontSize: 0,
          iconSize: 22,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 28),
          unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(1),
          selectedLabelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.merge(TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
          unselectedLabelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.merge(TextStyle(fontSize: 11)),
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          currentIndex: widget.currentTabIdx,
          onTap: (int i) {
            this._selectTab(i);
          },
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(IMAGE_ASSETS_ICONS_HOME) ,
              activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(IMAGE_ASSETS_ICONS_HOME, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Categories',
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(IMAGE_ASSETS_ICONS_CATEGORY),
              activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(IMAGE_ASSETS_ICONS_CATEGORY, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor) ,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(IMAGE_ASSETS_ICONS_ORDER_HISTORY, ) ,
              activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(IMAGE_ASSETS_ICONS_ORDER_HISTORY, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor ) ,
              label: 'Order History',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(IMAGE_ASSETS_ICONS_CART,) ,
              activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(IMAGE_ASSETS_ICONS_CART, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor) ,
              label: 'Cart',
            ),
          ],
```

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for. I wanted to style the labels and using this answer, I was able to.

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping your `BottomNavigationBar` in a `Container` then set its `color`.

Example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pages(),
      bottomNavigationBar:new Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text("Home")
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.work),
                title: Text("Self Help")
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.face),
                title: Text("Profile")
            )
          ],
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int i){setState((){index = i;});},
        fixedColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      );
    );
  };
```

Comment: don't set `appBar` at all if you're just making it null. it probably has a default value

Answer (score 4):

Just follow the given below code to customize according to your requirements. You just need to set the parent of NavigationBar with Theme and set **canvasColor** to change the background color

```
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      canvasColor: kOrangeMaterialColor
    ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      onTap: _onTapItem,

      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home,
        color: kWhiteColor,),
        label: ''),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications,
        color: kWhiteColor,),
        label: ''),
        // BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border,
        // color: kWhiteColor,),
       // label: ''),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle,
        color: kWhiteColor,),
        label: ''),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings,
        color: kWhiteColor,),
        label: ''),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code :

```
BottomNavigationBar (
backgroundColor: Colors.red,
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed
)
```

Or warp `BottomNavigation` with `Theme` widget and change `canvasColor`.

```
Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.green),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      // add your code ...
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the `backgroundColor` property to `BottomNavigationBar`widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      body: pages(),
      bottomNavigationBar:new BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
              title: new Text("Home")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.work),
              title: new Text("Self Help")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.face),
              title: new Text("Profile")
          )
        ],
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int i){setState((){index = i;});},
        fixedColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

// it will work like this backgound color

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pedometer/widgets/const.dart';
import 'package:pedometer/widgets/const.dart';
import 'package:pedometer/widgets/const.dart';
import 'package:pedometer/widgets/icon.dart';

import 'dashbord.dart';

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
   DashbordScreen(),
  DashbordScreen(),
  DashbordScreen(),
  DashbordScreen(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
         backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 6, 17, 93),
         type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
           // iconFun(path:Icons.home,context: context )
            icon: Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.white,size: 35,),
            label: 'Home',
          //  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.auto_graph_outlined,color: Colors.white,size: 35),
            label: 'Business',
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.health_and_safety,color: Colors.white,size: 35),
            label: 'School',
           // backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings,color: Colors.white,size: 35),
            label: 'Settings',
         //   backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
BottomNavigationBar (
backgroundColor: Colors.red,
)
```

If not changing color with this wrap with material widget.

```
Material(
child:
BottomNavigationBar (
backgroundColor: Colors.red,
),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, 
  backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), 
  selectedItemColor: Colors.greenAccent,
  unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
  elevation: 0,
)
```

It's important to set elevation to zero to get the exact color especially when you set an opacity to the color