# Transparent bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

i am new to flutter. I am trying to achieve this UI

[image: screenshot]

I haven't found any use full solution to create transparent bottom navigation bar in flutter.

I have tried using

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        icon: e,
        activeIcon: _activeIcons[_index],
        title: Text(
          title[_index],
          style: AppStyle.tabBarItem,
        ),
      )
```

But this doesn't seems to work. Please help.

Comment: I think this might be what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307858/style-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter

Comment: i have tried it just now, but it's not working. Can you please upvote this question? i am new to stack-overflow and people are downvoting.

Comment: Can you show you using the `Theme` method @magicleon94 linked to just so we can see possibly why it's not working?

Comment: Right now I can't since I'm at work. If I could, I would've explained how to adapt the linked question to your need. As for now, I've just that the linked answer solves the background need for a NavigationBar.

Comment: Thinking deeper, I'm realizing that this would not deliever the same result as the desired, since the image of the two girls would be above the NavigationBar. I suggest to use a `Stack` with the two girls image as the bottom layer (bottom of the stack) and a full screen `Column` with `MainAxisSize` set to `MainAxisSize.max` and `MainAxisAlignment` set to `MainAxisAlignment.end`. I could write it in an answer but I cannot test it right now, so I prefer to write a comment instead. Hope it helps

Comment: @SnakeyHips Here is output for that answer with transparent background https://imgur.com/a/0DzIfXb. Maybe because bottomNavigationbar don't have anything below it that why we aren't seeing anything.

Comment: @magicleon94 That's interesting, so you are saying i should put stack as child for column?

Comment: Nope, I'm saying you use a `Stack` with two children: an image (bottom layer) and a column (top layer) made as I wrote before

Comment: In a bit I'll see if I can have a quick try and provide you a working solution

Comment: Done, hope it helps!

Comment: Oh, I was late :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My attempt using the Stack method discussed in the comments:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/background.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Theme(
                    data: Theme.of(context)
                        .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
                    child: BottomNavigationBar(
                      currentIndex: 0,
                      items: [
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home'))
                      ],
                    ))),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: transparent bottom nav]

Edit: The `BottomNavigationBar` has an inbuilt elevation of `8.0` which you can't change and is causing that weird shadow effect. If you want to remove it, you could just implement your own kind of bottom bar like so:

```
Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,), onPressed: () {},),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,), onPressed: () {},),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,), onPressed: () {},),
                ],)),
```

[image: transparent nav demo 2]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved my day. can you help out with another question? I want ListItem to occupy full available height and width but it doesn't seems to work work with Expanded.

Comment: let me create another question for this.

Comment: No problem but I imagine you'd want to use something else other than a `ListTile` as they have a fixed height afaik.

Comment: Which other collection structure provides such capabilities?

Comment: A `ListView` doesn't HAVE to consist of `ListTile`s, the children can be any kind of Widget so I imagine you could just use a `Row` or create your own version of a `ListTile`.

Answer (score 88):

None of the given answers worked for me and I figured out something very important: you have to add the property [`extendBody: true`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html)

> If true, and bottomNavigationBar or persistentFooterButtons is specified, **then the body extends to the bottom of the Scaffold, instead of only extending to the top of the bottomNavigationBar or the persistentFooterButtons.**
>
> This property is often useful when the bottomNavigationBar has a non-rectangular shape, like CircularNotchedRectangle, which adds a FloatingActionButton sized notch to the top edge of the bar. In this case specifying extendBody: true ensures that that scaffold's body will be visible through the bottom navigation bar's notch

along with `backgroundColor: Color(0x00ffffff),` .

NB: color with 0x is hexadecimal ARGB value (0xAARRGGBB), so 00 before the ffffff means maximum transparency, you can play to increase opacity by increasing the 00 up to ff (255 in hexadecimal).

[image]

Full code example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  static int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  NavigationBarState createState() => NavigationBarState();
}

class NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      NavigationBar._selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 0, // to get rid of the shadow
        currentIndex: NavigationBar._selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        backgroundColor: Color(0x00ffffff), // transparent, you could use 0x44aaaaff to make it slightly less transparent with a blue hue.
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.grade),
            label: 'Level',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            label: 'Notification',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Achievements',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ]
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Then where your have the MaterialApp return:

```
return MaterialApp(
                home: Scaffold(
                    extendBody: true, // very important as noted
                    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(), // here you make use of the transparent bar.
                    body: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: ExactAssetImage("assets/background.png"), // because if you want a transparent navigation bar I assume that you have either a background image or a background color. You need to add the image you want and also authorize it in pubspec.yaml
                                fit: BoxFit.fill
                            ),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                              // the body of your app
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: This should be the official accepted answer! It's so simple. Instead of using a double or triple scaffold lol

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. Also, if you have SafeArea Widget in your widget tree, you might have to set bottom to false. (SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child:...)

Comment: best answer, I can use this with another plugin for navbar

Comment: also add `type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,` in short info above the code, tnx

Comment: This is awesome, literally just needed to add one property and everything fell into its rightful places, should be the answer for sure, nothing hacky, no workarounds, good job!

Answer (score 10):

This is how I achieve this

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Container(
          decoration: bgAuthenticationDecoration(),
          child: _HomeBodyWidget(_currentIndex),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home,),title: Container()),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.message),title: Container()),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.list),title: Container()),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),title: Container()),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),title: Container()),
      ],
      backgroundColor:Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      extendBody: true,
    );
```

Then you have to set the canvas color to transparent in app theme.

```
canvasColor: Colors.transparent
```

Hope this will help.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

In the new Version of flutter(1.2.1) there is a parameter for elevation, you can just put
**elevation: 0.0**

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach:

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/17/16/24/cat-3684184_960_720.jpg")
            )
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera), title: Text("Test")),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera), title: Text("Test")),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
```

This will fill the entire screen (the image is purely trivial but you get the thing) with a background image (bottom layer) and a bottom navigation bar inside a column whose content is aligned to `end`.

For a completion purpose I'll paste below the explaination I gave into the comments of the original question.

> Thinking deeper, I'm realizing that this would not deliever the same
>   result as the desired, since the image of the two girls would be above
>   the NavigationBar. I suggest to use a Stack with the two girls image
>   as the bottom layer (bottom of the stack) and a full screen Column
>   with MainAxisSize set to MainAxisSize.max and MainAxisAlignment set to
>   MainAxisAlignment.end. I could write it in an answer but I cannot test
>   it right now, so I prefer to write a comment instead. Hope it helps

**UPDATE**
The previous solution still had the navbar shadow.
This build method for the screen (the widget) does not, since I've implemented my own `BottomNavigationBar` with a `Row`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      "https://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/macinmac-portrat-splash.jpg"))),
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("Tap!");
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.photo_camera,
                      size: 50,
                    )),
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("Tap!");
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.photo_camera,
                      size: 50,
                    )),
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("Tap!");
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.photo_camera,
                      size: 50,
                    )),
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("Tap!");
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.photo_camera,
                      size: 50,
                    )),
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
```

Here's a screenshot from my phone:

[image: Example]

**Bonus**

You can achieve full screen by calling

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877288/hide-android-status-bar-on-flutter-app)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved my day. can you help out with another question? I want ListItem to occupy full available height and width but it doesn't seems to work work with Expanded.

Comment: Oh, no I don't think so. I was slower, no problem, I'll gradly take just an upvote as a consolation prize :)

Comment: let me create another question for this.

Comment: Haha sorry @magicleon94! Does your method still have the elevation shadow on the navbar?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. Wait a sec, I'll provide a screenshot too.

Comment: Oh sorry yeah it has, I hadn't noticed since I used a dark image!

Comment: Ah shame. At least you can still kinda make your own navbar.

Comment: Done, I'm updating the answer

Comment: I have updated the answer with a non-shadowed `NavigationBar`-like layout. It has buttons and taps, on the bottom, like a `NavigationBar`, even if it's still a normal `Row`. This should be what you're asking for

Answer (score 1):

My solution on high level:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  child(),
                  child(),
                  child(),
                  child(),
                  child(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Opacity(opacity: showBottomBar ? 1 : 0, child: bottomBar()),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

the idea being a stack with a scrollable view on the lower level and an aligned custom bottom bar on top of it

Answer (score 1):

**It's pretty simple with BottomNavigationBar.**

Just add these attributes only in BottomNavigationBar,

```
backgroundColor: Color(0x00ffffff),
elevation: 0,
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```

*After adding these my code looks like this.*

```
BottomNavigationBar(
selectedItemColor: MyTheme.primary_color,
unselectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(153, 153, 153, 1),
backgroundColor: Color(0x00ffffff),
elevation: 0,
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
currentIndex: _currentIndex,
onTap: (index) {
_currentIndex = index;                  
},
items: [
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, good news for you, I found the solution, and it's very easy!

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// Set Android Bar Transparent
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    //NavigationBar
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarContrastEnforced: false,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    //StatusBar
    // systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: false,
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(  
  floatingActionButton: _buildTransparentButton()
)
```

You can try floatingActionButton.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by assigning transparency to the background color:

`backgroundColor: const Color(0x00FFFFFF)`

0x00 = 0% opacity

Answer (score 0):

2022 solution
it's very very simpgle

1 - transparent color
2 - zero elevation

```
BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this three changes:-

use the `extendBody` property of the Scaffold widget and set it to **true**

set the backgrund color of BottomNavigationBar to transparent  `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent`

Set `elevation` to zero to remove the shadow         `elevation: 0,`

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
            label: 'Explore',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.redAccent,
//         onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

How to **customize BottomNavigationBar** in **2023**:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    selectedItemColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
    unselectedItemColor: kAccentColor,
    backgroundColor: kMainColor,
    elevation: 0,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(
            Icons.one_x_mobiledata,
          color: kAccentColor,
        ),
        label: 'Selected',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.two_k,
          color: kAccentColor,
        ),
        label: 'Unselected',
      ),
      
    ],
  ),

const kMainColor = Color(0xff071330);

const kAccentColor = Color(0xffC3CEDA);
```

Answer (score -4):

Found a solution for transparent `BottomNavigationBar`.

1. Open the the source code of `BottomNavigationBar` using the shortcut **Ctrl+B**.
2. Scroll through the file you will find a method named `Widget build`.
3. On that you can find a `Stack widget` where you can find a material widget.
4. Add `shadowColor:Colors.transparent`

Now You Get A Transparent `BottomNavigationBar`

Comment: Please, do not modify the flutter framework itself or you will have issues when upgrading.