# Flutter: How to show content behind bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that has a `bottomNavigationBar()` wrapped in a `clipRRect()` but the content doesn't show behind it. The same behaviour also happens with transparent `SliverAppBar()`s in `NestedScrollView()`s. How can I achieve this?

Edit: Here is an example of the `SliverAppBar()` problem. The shadow is being hidden by the app bar.

[image]

Comment: plz check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366982/transparent-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter

Comment: @ghostdeathrider it worked, thanks! Is there no way to do this other than this hacky workaround?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's there. I am also new to flutter and learning now, so I don't know exactly. Glad it worked. Please post the solution, so that if others have the problem they can refer to this. @Hady

Comment: @ghostdeathrider This solves the first problem. I still have the problem of a transparent SliverAppBar not showing the content below it when in a `NestedScrollView()`. Any way how to solve that? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Dude but this isn't a normal app bar, it is a SliverAppBar. The structure of this page is a `Scaffold()` widget with a body of `NestedScrollView()` I have the `SliverAppBar()` and the `ListView.builder()` in the `NestedScrollView()`. Would it still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
Scaffold(
            extendBody: true,
            extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
```

and give a little padding to the top and bottom of you body content for overlapping at the very top and bottom.

Comment: Ok, i'll try it out and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Will the extendBodyBehindAppBar work if I am using a `SliverAppBar()`? Because I don't have an `AppBar()` in the scaffold but a sliver app bar in a `NestedScrollView()`.

Comment: you cannot avoid the SliverAppBar clipping your SliverList/ListView, but you can add a little more padding to SliverList/ListView to give top more space for shadow