# Nav bar Indicator for which tab is selected isn't working

Tags: android, flutter

this is my second thread to this Topic, this time I will ad a picture and the full code.
The nav bar is working but I want an indicator on which is pressed (the text under the icon is already scaling up a bit but thats not enough)
I want hat the segment which is pressed has a more light background then the others.
How is that possible? I'm really new to Flutter and currently this is the only programming language which is complete confusing for me. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8ueX.jpg)
In the code, I just have included an icon font (font awesome) and 3 pages which the nav bar directs to. (neu, beliebt, profil)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'Neu.dart';
import 'Beliebt.dart';
import 'Profil.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    NeuPage(),
    BeliebtPage(),
    ProfilPage(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
            title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                  Image.asset(
                 'assets/logo_straight.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  height: 32,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),


        body: _pageOptions[_selectedTab],

        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedTab,
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedTab = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.quoteRight, color: Colors.white),
              title: Text('Neu', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot, color: Colors.white),
              title: Text('Beliebt', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.white),
              title: Text('Profil', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wellcome Mika to stackoverflow , try using activeIcon : Icon(Icons.whatshot, color: Colors.green),

Comment: Hmm that only chnges the color of the icon. But I want to change the background of the selected item

Answer (score 4):

### Possible Solutions

- Build your own Widget using row and columns
- Flutter is an open soruse project , edit the original Widget and submit it or use it your self

  - [here original Widget code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/365f577c707b092f9b97b62b0cdb331c2d7fcf75/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart)
- Paint over the Widget

  - Use a Container , Stack and the bottomNavigationBar size to move the Container
  - **this is what i used here**

### Screen Record

[image]

### Step 1

inside **MyAppState** add **GlobalKey** variable

```dart
GlobalKey _bottomNavigationBarKey = GlobalKey();
```

### Step 2

assign the **GlobalKey** to the **BottomNavigationBar**

```dart
BottomNavigationBar(
   key: _bottomNavigationBarKey,
...)
```

### Step 3

inside **MyAppState** add **_bottomNavigationBarSize** variable

```dart
  Size _bottomNavigationBarSize = Size(0, 0);
```

### Step 4

inside **MyAppState** add **_getbottomNavigationBarSize** method to ask the framework for the bottomNavigationBar **Size**

```dart
 _getbottomNavigationBarSize() {
    final RenderBox bottomNavigationBarRenderBox =
        _bottomNavigationBarKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final bottomNavigationBarSize = bottomNavigationBarRenderBox.size;
    setState(() {
      _bottomNavigationBarSize = bottomNavigationBarSize;
    });
  }
```

### Step 5

inside **initState** at **addPostFrameCallback** call **_getbottomNavigationBarSize** method to tell the framework to calculate the size after the frame drawing is done

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _getbottomNavigationBarSize());
  }
```

### Step 6

warp the **bottomNavigationBar** Widget in a **Stack** Widget

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: 
 Stack
 (
  children: <Widget>
    [
    BottomNavigationBar(.....),
   ],
 )
```

### Step 7

add an **Positioned** Widget after **BottomNavigationBar**

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: 
 Stack
 (
  children: <Widget>
    [
    BottomNavigationBar(.....),
    Positioned(.....),
   ],
 )
```

### Step 8

set the **Positioned** Widget **left** property

- item width =  ***bottomNavigationBar width** dividend by the **pages count**
- 1st item offset  = 0 * item width = 0
- 2st item end  = 1 * item width = item width
- 2st item end  = 2 *item width = 2 item width
- container offset  =  item width multiplied by the _selectedTab index

```dart
Positioned(
  left: (_bottomNavigationBarSize.width / _pageOptions.length) * _selectedTab,
),
```

### Step 9

add an **Positioned** Widget after **BottomNavigationBar**

```dart
Positioned
(
  ...,
  child: Container(.... ),
)
```

### Step 10

in the **Container** set the **height** property to bottomNavigationBar height

```dart
   Container(
      height: _bottomNavigationBarSize.height,
      ....),
```

### Step 10

in the **Container** set the **width** property to bottomNavigationBar width divided by the pages count

```dart
   child: Container(
      width: _bottomNavigationBarSize.width / _pageOptions.length,
      ....),
```

### Step 11

in the **Container** set the **color** property to Black with 26% opacity.

```dart
   child: Container(
      ....,
      color: Colors.black26)
```

### Full Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationBarKey = GlobalKey();

  Size _bottomNavigationBarSize = Size(0, 0);
  _getbottomNavigationBarSize() {
    final RenderBox bottomNavigationBarRenderBox =
        _bottomNavigationBarKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final bottomNavigationBarSize = bottomNavigationBarRenderBox.size;
    setState(() {
      _bottomNavigationBarSize = bottomNavigationBarSize;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _getbottomNavigationBarSize());
  }

  int _selectedTab = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  final _pageOptions = [
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
            title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("Image"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: _pageOptions[_selectedTab],
        bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            BottomNavigationBar(
              key: _bottomNavigationBarKey,
              currentIndex: _selectedTab,
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedTab = index;
                });
              },
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: Colors.white),
                  title: Text(
                    'Neu',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot, color: Colors.white),
                    title: Text(
                      'Beliebt',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.white),
                    title: Text(
                      'Profil',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: (_bottomNavigationBarSize.width / _pageOptions.length) *
                  _selectedTab,
              child: Container(
                  height: _bottomNavigationBarSize.height,
                  width: _bottomNavigationBarSize.width / _pageOptions.length,
                  color: Colors.black26),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Ref

- [Get size and position of a widget in Flutter - Coflutter](https://coflutter.com/flutter/get-size-and-position-of-a-widget-in-flutter/)

Comment: @MikaCmn thank you for accepting my answer please clicked the accept button

Answer (score 0):

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49315233/8151468) I think that might help you , basically it says that you should wrap you nav bar inside material widget (not MatrialApp widget) and override the theme and specify another for your nav bar.