# Flutter BottomNavigationBar backgroundColor ignored for

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I ran into this odd behavior today, seems that the backgroundColor does not work on the BottomNavigationBar if it is set as shifting. The background color cannot be chnaged either locally or by trying to setup a them in the main app Theme : bottomNavigationBarTheme:BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
backgroundColor: Colors.red,),.

```
child: BottomNavigationBar(
            iconSize: 20,
            selectedFontSize: 8,
            unselectedFontSize: 0,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
            onTap: _selectPage,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
```

Does anyone know what the workaround for this is?

Comment: Means you want to change bottom navigation bar color ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980396/7776801

Comment: Question should be more than clear Shubham Narkhede ... And Jose Georges thank you for your post it explains everything but I cannot seem to select it as the answer.