# In Flutter, how can I change the font of the items in a BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've searched for the answer to this question on stackoverflow, without luck. From similar questions ([Style BottomNavigationBar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307858/style-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter))I realise I should set the theme as per below

The answer lies in the need to set the textTheme bodyText2

```
return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                caption: GoogleFonts.aclonica(),
        )), // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            currentIndex: 0,
            fixedColor: Colors.teal,
            items: items.map((item) {
              return BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: item.label,
                icon: getIconExcl(context, item),
              );
            }).toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, one only needs to know which textTheme to set. Don't use caption, use bodyText2 as per below

```
return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                bodyText2: GoogleFonts.aclonica(),
        )), // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            currentIndex: 0,
            fixedColor: Colors.teal,
            items: items.map((item) {
              return BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: item.label,
                icon: getIconExcl(context, item),
              );
            }).toList()));
```