# Label text color is not changing in bottom navigation bar widget in scaffold, flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I used
selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize: 25,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
color: Colors.black,
),

But the text color is still blue. Any idea how to fix it? [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please paste the full code in your question, not a picture of the code.

Comment: I wanted to show what i did and the result. The actual code is messy so i posted a portion of it.

Answer (score 2):

The text color can be changed with the `selectedItemColor` in the [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)
(It will also set the selected Color of the Icon but you have probably overwritten that in the icons)

```dart
BottomNavigationBar(
    selectedItemColor:  Colors.black,
    items: ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
    bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
        canvasColor: Colors.green,
        // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
        textTheme: Theme
            .of(context)
            .textTheme
            .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow))), // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
    child: new BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: 0,
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
          title: new Text("Add"),
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
          title: new Text("Delete"),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

**Next One another Example:**

```
    BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, 
  backgroundColor: Colors.black, // 
  selectedItemColor: Colors.greenAccent,
  unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.call),
      label: 'Call',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.message),
      label: 'Message',
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image: Preview]

See On [Style BottomNavigationBar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307858/style-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter)