# flutter BottomNavigationBarThemeData(selectedItemColor) is not working

Tags: flutter

I'm making application bottomNavigaionBar and I want to make it when I click  the button then it changes color. So I used selectedItemColor and I make button home and shop but the problem I asking for question is that the selectedItemColor is only work for home not for shop. How can solve this?

```
var theme = ThemeData(
  bottomNavigationBarTheme:
  BottomNavigationBarThemeData(selectedItemColor: Colors.pink),
  iconTheme:IconThemeData(color:  Colors.blue),   // appbar 에 적용 안됨
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
    bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)
  ),
  textButtonTheme:TextButtonThemeData(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink
    )
  ),
```

It's style code above.

Answer (score 0):

When you define new styles and theme you need to get out of app and start againt to load it, and make sure you pass you theme to `MaterialApp` theme meyhod:

```
BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
    selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.black12,
)
```

I think you didnt get out of run and restart it againt

[BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) has selectedColor method and unselected too but if you need use theme
and if didnt work again! Warp your navigationBar with `Theme`, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307858/style-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter) to findout