How to delete the background white block of bottomNavigationbar in flutter normally
I don't know why the bottomNavigationbar will have a white flash when the keyboard is folded up
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outlineVariant.withOpacity(0.5), blurRadius: 12),
              ],
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 38, bottom: 7),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14, vertical: 4),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                FilledButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('add')),
                FilledButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('add')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            const SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 1')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 2')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 3')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 4')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 5')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 6')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 6')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 6')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 7')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: TextField(),
            ),
            SliverList.builder(
                itemBuilder: (v, a) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(title: Text('Item $a')),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: 10),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I don't know why the bottomNavigationbar will have a white flash when the keyboard is folded up
When clicking on the input box to pop up the keyboard and then retract the keyboard, bottonNavigationBar will appear a white screen block flashing
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/7d503bd9-8ada-4622-9da4-8b9a8b96fad4

Check these articles 1. https://medium.com/yavar/changing-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-colors-in-flutter-54f02e45f119   2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307858/style-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter
